# Different Customer and Passenger on this Relational Database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have found a great relational database on internet. It's look about trains and plane ticketing booking. here's the image

[relationship database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN3M3.png)

My goal is, create real database based on that image. When I start analyze the Database pict, I bit confused with the Passenger and Customer table, is both of them is different?

Answer (score 0):

This is very common in our daily life.The customer is you that you go to buy some tickets for your whole family,and the passengers is your family.

Comment: is customer for known 'buyer', and passenger vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

The passenger is a person on the plane (or train).  This may or may not be the customer.  In addition, a customer may eventually be the passenger, but not until the flight is arranged.  If a customer changes flights or cancels their flight, they are still a customer, but they may no longer be a passenger of a specific flight.

In other words, a passenger is a person associated with a specific travel event.  The customer is a person associated with a purchase (the diagram calls it Booking).

It is fairly common for an entity to be defined based on the relationship to other entities.  For example, they could also have an agent table, defined as the person facilitating the booking.  The customer and agent are both persons, but it is the relationship to the booking that defines what attributes you are interested in capturing.